# Bessel integration with exponential function

Tags: bessel-functions

Could some one help me in evaluating this definite integral of Bbessel's function with an exponential function

$$\int_0^1 e^{-ar^2}J_1(\lambda_n r )dr= ?$$

where $\lambda_n$ is any of the roots of $J_1$ and $a$ is a constant.

Comment: Consider using MathJax for your posts here. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Perhaps try to integrate $\sum_{m =-\infty}^{\infty}  t^m J_m(r)  = e^{ r ( t - 1/t)/2}$ and then pick up the coefficient of $t = 1$?